# How to check if ppa:ondrej/php repository is added successfully?

Tags: apt, 18.04, php

I'm trying to install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04. I've executed the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

It looks finished successfully. After that I update the apt by:

```
apt update
```

And finally when I want to install PHP 7.4, by by the following command:

```
sudo apt install php7.4
```

It throws:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
```

[image]

Any idea what's the issue? Should I update Ubuntu sources.list? Is any issue related to `ppa:ondrej/php` repo?

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 is EOSS, the PPA you mention provides support only for LTS releases in *standard* support, ie. check https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php and you'll note support for 20.04 & 22.04 only.